# RobotFramework: Link/List with locator not found

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, xpath, robotframework

I am studying Robot Framework with Selenium Library and I can't figure out how to remove "kw" element from the next dropdown:

[image]

I tried to use xpath for it:

```
*** Settings ***
Library  SeleniumLibrary

*** Test Cases ***
MyTest
  Create Webdriver  Chrome  executable_path=chromedriver.exe
  Open Browser  http://127.0.0.1:85/  Chrome
  Sleep  10
  Click Link  xpath=//body/div[@id='react-entry-point']/div[@id='_dash-global-error-container']/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/span[1]
```

But it doesn't work. I am getting:

```
Link with locator 'xpath=//body/div[@id='react-entry-point']/div[@id='_dash-global-error-container']/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/span[1]' not found.
```

If I try `//span[text()='kw']` or `//span[contains(.,'kw')]` or `//div[@class='Select-value']//span[contains(.,'kw')]` I would get the same error.

Also I tried to access to this element via **List by Value** instead of **Click Link**:

```
  Unselect From List by Value  xpath=//body/div[@id='react-entry-point']/div[@id='_dash-global-error-container']/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/span[1]
```

But I am getting an error:

```
List with locator 'xpath=//body/div[@id='react-entry-point']/div[@id='_dash-global-error-container']/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/span[1]' not found.
```

Here is HTML code for dropdown menu:

```
  <div style="display: inline-block; height: 20px; width: 300px; margin-left: 25px;" xpath="1"><div id="Type_id" class="dash-dropdown"><div class="Select has-value is-clearable is-searchable Select--multi"><div class="Select-control"><div class="Select-multi-value-wrapper" id="react-select-2--value"><div class="Select-value"><span class="Select-value-icon" aria-hidden="true">×</span><span class="Select-value-label" role="option" aria-selected="true" id="react-select-2--value-0">kw<span class="Select-aria-only">&nbsp;</span></span></div><div class="Select-value"><span class="Select-value-icon" aria-hidden="true">×</span><span class="Select-value-label" role="option" aria-selected="true" id="react-select-2--value-1">teardown<span class="Select-aria-only">&nbsp;</span></span></div><div class="Select-value"><span class="Select-value-icon" aria-hidden="true">×</span><span class="Select-value-label" role="option" aria-selected="true" id="react-select-2--value-2">setup<span class="Select-aria-only">&nbsp;</span></span></div><div class="Select-input" style="display: inline-block;"><input id="Type_id" aria-activedescendant="react-select-2--value" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="false" aria-owns="" role="combobox" value="" style="box-sizing: content-box; width: 5px;"><div style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; visibility: hidden; height: 0px; overflow: scroll; white-space: pre; font-size: 15px; font-family: &quot;Open Sans&quot;, HelveticaNeue, &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: 400; font-style: normal; letter-spacing: normal; text-transform: none;"></div></div></div><span aria-label="Clear all" class="Select-clear-zone" title="Clear all"><span class="Select-clear">×</span></span><span class="Select-arrow-zone"><span class="Select-arrow"></span></span></div></div></div></div>
```

Here is a link to full HTML code:
https://jsfiddle.net/illuminato/u24j6wbh/

Comment: This `xpath=//body/div[@id='react-entry-point']/div[@id='_dash-global-error-container']/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/span[1]` is quite error-prone. Could you simplify it?

Comment: @pavelsaman Sorry, but I don't know how it could be done.I just copy this xpath via "inspect element" in browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the below keyword and locator:

```
Click Element    //span[text()='kw']/../*[@class="Select-value-icon"]
```

Click Link  match is based on "on link text and href." as span is not a link it may not work